# Programm Start and End after 30 Minutes

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have an Windows MSC (Microsoft Management Console), that should end after 30 Minutes because the main memory is with the plugins very high.

1. I start the Powershell script
2. The PowerShell open the MMC
3. after 30 minutes PowerShell is to be terminated the MMC

How does it Work?

Comment: Why do you need to leave this plugin running for so long, and why can't the memory usage be fixed/reduced? Fix the root cause, don't band-aid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$p = Start-Process mmc -PassThru;

$time = ( Get-Date ).AddMinutes( 30 );

while ( $true )
{
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; #or Millseconds

  if ( $time -lt ( Get-Date ) )
  {
    if ( -not $p.HasExited )
    {
      $p.Kill();
    }

    break;
  }
}
```

Thx for comments.

Comment: A loop is not required, and in this case will consume far too many CPU cycles. Just use `start-sleep -seconds 1800` between the `start-process` and `end-process`

Comment: @alroc In my experience sleeping short intervals in a loop until a fixed end time is more reliable than sleeping a single extended amount of time. `$time = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(30); do { Start-Sleep -Millseconds 200 } until ((Get-Date) -gt $time)`

Comment: `Stop-Process -Name mmc` will indiscriminately terminate all processes with that name, which may not be desired. It's better to start the process like this: `$p = Start-Process mmc -PassThru`. That way you have a handle to that particular process and can terminate it via `$p.Kill()` after the timer expired.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I'd suggest a different kind of loop than the one proposed by [@MrDywar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32480977/1630171).

```
$p = Start-Process mmc -PassThru

$expiration = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(30)

do {
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
} until ($p.HasExited -or (Get-Date) -gt $expiration)

if (-not $p.HasExited) { $p.Kill() }
```

This avoids breaking from an infinite loop as well as indiscriminately continuing for the set amount of time (even when the process ended before the timer expired).